# MySQL update isn't updating

Tags: mysql

```
<?php
require("header.inc.php");
?>

<?php
if (isLoggedIn()) {
    if (isset($_POST['CKey_Button'])) {
        if (!isset($_POST['CKey'])) {
            die("Error: The Character Key field was not set.");
        }
    }

    $CKey = $_POST['CKey_Button'];

    mysql_select_db("samp");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `CharacterKey` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CKey']) . "' LIMIT 1");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
        mysql_select_db("ucp");
        mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `CharacterID` = '" . $CKey . "' WHERE `name` = '" . $user['name'] . "'");
        header("./Dashboard.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("./index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else {
    header("./index.php");
    exit;   
}
?>
```

That is the code but it isn't updating and it just a blank screen, does anyone know why this could be happening(I have just started coding php so be nice if it's a newbie error).

EDIT: I have fixed it I was using $CKey as the button and not the actual key, hope this makes sense, I also changed = '" . $CKey . "' to = " . $CKey

Comment: Are u sure $user['name'] contains a value ?
Also its : header('Location: dashboard.php');

Comment: If the CharacterID field is numeric, you should lose the quotes.  Change `= '" . $CKey . "'` to `= " . $CKey . "`.

Comment: Please, the next thing you do should be to read up on [SQL injection issues](http://bobby-tables.com/) and how to properly [escape SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code is extremely dangerous.

Comment: So is the problem now resolved?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks anyways man.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_error()` to see if there is any error in your query

```
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());
```

Comment: Ok I have done some editing and I now get this error, 'WHERE `name` = 'Account_Name'' at line 1 heres the edited code: $user = getUser();
  mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `CharacterID` = " . $CKey . " WHERE `name` = '" . $user['name'] . "' ");

Comment: Put the query in a variable so you can echo it. Then update your post with the query so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: yes echo your query and then may be try to run it in your mysql and see what is the error.

Comment: ok great ! edit your question description about what you had done for fixing so that others are been helped.